# try to retrieve data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read from a firebase database to my app but it does not work after several effort.

This is the firebase database:
[image: this is the firebase database]

I am trying to retrieve the two value from kids like this:

```
sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String UserId = sharedPref.getString("firebasekey", "");

final TextView mkid1ID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kid1);
final TextView mkid2ID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kid2);


mDatabaseUser_Kid1ID = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(UserId).child("Kid1ID");
mDatabaseUser_Kid2ID = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(UserId).child("kid2ID");

mDatabaseUser_Kid2ID.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mkid2ID.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});




mDatabaseUser_Kid1ID.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mkid1ID.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

to a layout like this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/kid1"
    android:clickable="true"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/kid2"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

i am new to android development please i need help thanks

Comment: Make sure to follow at least the first tutorial here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/ that should help you a lot !

Comment: dont do anything use the below line:

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("UserId").child(kids)
.child("kid1ID")

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `kids` from your JSON structure in your database references:

```
mDatabaseUser_Kid1ID = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(UserId).child("kids/kid1ID");
mDatabaseUser_Kid2ID = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(UserId).child("kids/kid2ID");
```

---

Aside from that, I would probably simplify the code to use a single listener on all of the users `kids` and then just read the two properties on the single `onDataChange`:

```
mDatabaseUser_Kids = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(UserId).child("kids");

mDatabaseUser_Kids.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mkid1ID.setText(dataSnapshot.child("kid1ID").getValue(String.class));
        mkid2ID.setText(dataSnapshot.child("kid2ID").getValue(String.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseErrors.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a capital K in the top code part: `Kid1ID`, and small k in the bottom code. Remember Firebase is case sensitive.

Comment: Good catch Andre. That uppercase `K` actually came from the question, and would be another reason why the original code doesn't work. Fixed it in my answer now. If you find any more such mistakes, feel free to edit straight away. ;-)

Answer (score -4):

Use this method

```
    private void getDataFrom() {

        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("kids");

        mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if (map.get("kid1ID") != null) {
                        kid1ID= map.get("title").toString();
                        Log.i("kid1ID",String.valueOf(kid1ID));

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is almost the exact same code as the other answer.